# Cant persist an entity

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, hsqldb

I use JPA 2.0 for my project.

I delete and entity and then try to persist same data but it throws :

`org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge` .

Below is what I am performing :

```
for(Education edu : educations) {
    entManager.remove(edu);
    Education tempEdu = new Education();
    tempEdu.setCourse(edu.getCourse());
    tempEdu.setInstitution(edu.getInstitution());
    tempEdu.setPlace(edu.getPlace());
    tempEdu.setFromDate(edu.getFromDate());
    tempEdu.setToDate(edu.getToDate());
    tempEdu.setMember(updatedMem);
    entManager.merge(tempEdu);
}
```

Can you tell me how to remove an entity and then persist its data in another entity?

Regards,

Satya

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `remove` operation cascades to some of the relationships, which you are using later:

```
tempEdu.setCourse(edu.getCourse());
tempEdu.setInstitution(edu.getInstitution());
tempEdu.setPlace(edu.getPlace());
```

Try commenting these line and see whether it works. If so, you must either remove cascading on this relationships or create copy of of this objects just as you are doing it with `tempEdu`.

And this leads to the question already asked by *axtavt* - what are you trying to achieve? You'll end up deleting bunch of objects and then recreating them and saving back...

Comment: The cascade feature is not working in my application and couldnt trace why it was behaving like that. So what I am trying is : If any entity is deleted/edited/added in UI, I delete all related entities and then recreate the ones which come from UI. By this way, I will be deleting the ones deleted in UI, add new ones and also updated the modified ones.

Answer (score 0):

As posted by you in comments - *If any entity is deleted/edited/added in UI, I delete all related entities and then recreate the ones which come from UI ...*

Maintain two lists, one for entities in database & another for UI.

```
//---

dbEntries.removeAll(uiEntries);  // dbEntries will have entities to be deleted 

for(Education edu : dbEntries){

  em.remove(edu);  // Deleting entries not found in UI
}

for(Education edu : uiEntries){

  em.merge(edu);  // Updating existing entity else persisting new one
}

//---
```

This way you can achieve what you are trying so far, point out if I got it wrong.

Else in your code, try merging tempEdu before removing edu.